# How to fake cookie for HTTP fake respond?

Tags: laravel, cookies, phpunit, guzzle

I want to mock a HTTP response in Laravel with cookie. I tried this:

```
Http::fake([
    'my-mocked-route' => Http::response(['foo' => 'bar'], 200)->withCookie('a', 10),
]);
```

but I receive

> Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Promise\FulfilledPromise::withCookie()

same if I just use `cookie` instead of `withCookie`. Also, I would to add Cookie attributes aswell.

I also tried

```
Http::fake([
     
        'qnnect' => Http::response(['foo' => 'bar'], 200, ['Cookie' => 'a=10; Expiration=Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT']),
    ]);
```

And although the response contains correct cookies in the header, `$response->cookies()` returns an empty CookieJar.

Is there a possibility to mock cookies in the respond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct header is `Set-Cookie` and not `Cookie`. Domain is also required.

```php
  Http::fake([
    'home' => Http::response('Ok', 200, ['Set-Cookie' => 'foo=bar; domain=.'])
  ]);

  $response = Http::get('home');
  dump($response->cookies()->getCookieByName('foo')->getValue());
```

Output will be `bar`

Comment: Nice, your right. How can I set multiple attributes like domain and expired?

Comment: Found it: `['Set-Cookie' => 'a=10; Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT; domain=.']),` seems to work :))

Comment: Just check out documentation for the set-cookie header https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie for all available options

Comment: Yes I was checking already, but the docs say just add multiple "Set-Cookie" options, which is of course not possible in an php array, as you can have a key only once. But it seems that if you seperate with semicolon in one line, it will magically work

Answer (score 1):

`->withCookies` is a method you can use on `Http::fake()` and not on `Http::response()`

Comment: What should I use as second parameter domain? I tried the fake url aswell as `'.'` both didn't work. Also, I think this method may not work for me, as I want to set Exparation date as well.